# How to set ca-bundle path for OpenSSL in ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, certificate, ca

I am experiencing a problem in ruby, where an SSL cert could not be validated by OpenSSL. I think this is caused by the ca-bundle.pem not being known by the script. Is there a possibility to configure the path of the ca-bundle.pem manually?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OpenSSL uses the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable. You can set it in your ruby script using something like before the first `require` which pulls in OpenSSL:

```
ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = '/path/to/ca-bundle.pem'
```

or, if you prefer, you can set the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable in your OS environment, web server configuration etc depending on your situation.

Answer (score 8):

You can do so by the following:

```
SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: Where do I have to put this? fyi I am running Windows

Comment: This is to be put in the ruby code itself.not sure how to do it in a windows system. alternatively you can disable the certificate verification altogether by doing:

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Comment: yeah, i dont like to disable the verification ... due to security issues. Is there a constant, that can be set for the OpenSSL module? OpenSSL::SSL::XX = path ???

Answer (score 0):

It's all because `SSL_CERT_FILE` has a wrong value, the value it has might not exist. So, you have to set its value to your certificate file as `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE]='path/to/ca-bundle.p'`. If you are using Rails, you can put it in an initializer. If you want a gem that does everything for you, use https://github.com/stevegraham/certified.