# OpenSSL add CA for certificate verification

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, public-key-encryption

Trying to connect to a SSL website using ruby (https://bank.barclays.co.uk/olb/auth/LoginLink.action)

When I connect I get the following error:

```
:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate     verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I have tried all the existing solutions:

- update gem (using 2.0.3) & openssl (using 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.8)
- adding 'ssl_verify_mode' to .gemrc

I need to use SSL verify and high level security because Im going to be transferring secure passcodes to a bank.

I think the problem is that the SSL CA of the receiving website is not trusted by my computer. However, rather than configure the OS to trust the certificate natively, Id rather find a solution that does not rely on the OS (preferably something where I can pass a configuration to OpenSSL on runtime).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748701/how-to-set-ca-bundle-path-for-openssl-in-ruby helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), you can do this:

```
Typhoeus::Request.get(url.to_s, :disable_ssl_peer_verification => true)
```